# outputing html not json

Tags: java, php, mysql, json

I have been doing a tutorial on connecting android to mysql using php and I keep getting this error message

```
error parsing data org.json.JOSNException:VALUE<HTML><TITLE>404
type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSON object
```

from this I gather there is something wrong in the php file can someone please tell me how to fix it

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 *   All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {

$name = $_POST['name'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products(name, price, description) VALUES('$name',                                        '$price', '$description')");

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: Looks like the URL you are fetching the JSON result from, is wrong.

Comment: You could also be receiving an error in the output, before the JSON is encoded. If you inspect the raw response - does it only contain JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Error `404` In HTTP means page not found most likely the URL is not incorrect.

Add the following to the top of your PHP:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```